# Skip authentication popup when running command from terminal - Just fail instead

Tags: command-line, 22.04

I'm coming from another distro where running a command that required administrator privileges through the terminal without `sudo` would cause the command to fail, usually while printing out a message requesting super user access.

Ubuntu 22.04 instead opens a GUI "Authentication Required" popup asking me to authenticate for some commands (e.g. `systemctl start`). I spend a lot of time in the terminal and I'm not going to lie my muscle memory for handling a failed command is pretty baked-in. Having to relearn keystrokes to interact with the GUI is workable, but not my favorite.

Is there any way to disable this popup and just have the commands fail? Or better yet, prompt for authentication within the terminal itself?

Worth mentioning: I do NOT want to turn off password authentication for any commands on my machine, just the GUI popup.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a policykit thing and you can write rules following your specific polkit version's documentation ... But it's tricky for what you want and it requires per service/action rules, so one rule can't solve all "test" prompts AFAIK ... If you search for that, you'll get what I mean..